# Get Response Value in Java(Coffee)script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, response

With firebug, I got a response of this when upload is complete:

```
{"message":"News \"test\" successfully stored!"}
```

I want to get the value of the `message` of the response, so I tried this:

```
UploadService.news.save(fd).then (response) -> 
                    alert response.message.message
```

returns `a.message is undefined`, so I changed to `alert response.message`, returns `undefined`, then I change to `alert response`, it returns `Object object`. How can I get the value in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is `response.data.message`, if the `UploadService` is using `$http`. In any case and if you are using Firefox with Firebug or Chrome you can do `console.log(response)` instead of `alert(response)`. The console will show you the structure of the logged object so you can be sure.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand, what do you mean "why"? For AJAX with Angular you may be using the `$resource` somehow in which case the argument is slightly different.

Comment: I mean why `.data` works, I can't use `$resource` since I don't know how to post FormData with it (I tried using transformRequest but didn't work)

Comment: You don't have to use `$resource`, it is perfectly OK with `$http`. The `.data` is how it is specified by Angular see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), search for "The response object has these properties" for the full spec.